# Mini loft conversion help (UK)

Tags: insulation, attic

I have a very small loft (4sqm) that is part of an extension that sits above a utility room between my home and garage. I would like to turn the loft space into a small server closet due to a lack of suitable location in the house. Due to this, I would like to somewhat insulate the loft space to keep it warm in winter and cooler in summer to stop my equipment going kaput.

I have attached some images that hopefully give you an idea of what's going on.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sJwM.jpg

As you can see, the three walls in the loft are not external, so I am hoping there won't need to be any work done there. It is mostly the roof I am concerned about. To make clear, I don't intend for this to look like a nice space, my hope is to put simple loft boards down on the joists, insulated and plywood the roof area, and start screwing into the wall to hold equipment. I guess my questions are as follows;

1. Can I safely insulate between the rafters, or will this cause damp issues? Do I need to leave a gap? I have attached pictures of the membrane below the tiles, is this breathable?
2. If I insulated between the rafters, how do I close up the gap towards where the rafters meet the wall plate?
3. Do I then need to apply a moisture barrier over the insulation?
4. Do I need to put anything on the brick walls, or can they stay as-is?
5. Is there anything I have overlooked?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is difficult to get perspective of the space with the close-up photos. It also appears to have plumbing running through the space so presumably it already is not freezing in the winter time. ?? My first thought is, if you can afford it, closed cell spray foam insulation.

Comment: If you have enough equipment in there, you won't need to keep it warm in the winter - your equipment can do that so by itself. Keeping it cool in the summer is going to be your challenge.

Comment: Have you overlooked ventilation?